# Error getting endorser client for channel: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, amazon-managed-blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-orderer

I am getting an error message while following this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/hyperledger-fabric-dev/managed-blockchain-get-started-tutorial.html tutorial from Amazon Managed Blockchain for Hyperledger Fabric. I have followed all steps properly but I got stuck while trying to join a channel. I am a newbie in Hyperledger Fabric and Amazon Managed Blockchain. I have attached an image of the error message below. Help me!!!

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiZ9y.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting:

> Failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

Can be caused by:

- A misconfiguration of ChannelIDs. Make sure the ChannelIDs match and that you are attempting to join the peer to the correct channel.
- Using the wrong root certificate file for TLS. Make sure the root certificate file and root certificate path are correct.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71845408/hyperledger-fabric-peer-chaincode-instantiate-failed-to-create-new-connect) is a link to the question this answer was based on, involving the same error in a different context.