# Hyperledger Fabric - peer chaincode instantiate - " failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded "

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, chaincode

Im trying to instantiate my chaincode on my hyperledger fabric network of 3 peers and 3 orderers, but im getting the error:

> Failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

Here is a screenshot of the logs from both peer1 and iorderer1 nodes.

[Peer1](https://pastebin.com/VjvDauZ4)

[Orderer1](https://pastebin.com/p6QfWmvj)

```
orderer1.iaorderer.com IP Address: 172.23.0.12

peer1.iaorderer.com IP Address: 172.23.0.8
```

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Ewan99/InsurApp/tree/remake)

[Screenshot of the CLI Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjONy.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix my issue, which was due to a number of factors.

I had improperly configured ChannelIDs when generating the genesis block and default channel. Both commands were using the "default" channelID which caused issues

I was also accidentally joining the peer to the genesis channel instead of the default.

Finally I was using the wrong root-cert file when using TLS for communication.